# send push notifications from fullcalendar to ios

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, fullcalendar, push

I've a calendar that I've built with fullcalendar; I'd like that if a user change some details of an event, he could receive a push notification on his  iOS application (developed with cordova)

Is this possible? I can't find documentation on this.
Thank you!

Comment: fullcalendar is a client-side, browser-based tool. fullCalendar would have to notify your server (e.g. via an AJAX request), and then it can send out a push notification by whatever means. Or maybe there is some 3rd-party service where fullCalendar can make an AJAX request direct to that in order to trigger a push notification. AFAIK you cannot send a push notification direct from a browser.

Comment: uhm. Thanks for your opinion. I'm still looking for an idea or a solution.

Comment: It's not really an opinion, it's an explanation of the constraints of the browser environment and a concrete suggestion of how you need to implement your requirements in order to work within that structure.